# Using custom 3D objects with ARCore Augmented Faces

Tags: android, augmented-reality, blender, arcore, android-augmented-reality

I am trying to use multiple custom objects to be placed on the face using ARCore SDK. I import the face mesh FBX file provided by Google in the SDK using Blender and place my custom object relative to the face mesh. then I remove the face mesh and export the object as .obj file to be used inside my app.

However, the object is not shown at the position I placed it at relative to the face mesh.

I am using sceneform to render the object on the face.

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

[Google Documentation for adding custom objects](https://i.stack.imgur.com/apXtp.png)

I followed the same hierarchy google provided, I left the bones and removed the face mesh and set the main asset as a parent to my object,
but still the object is not placed correctly on the face.

[Blender Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/av2YG.jpg)

I added a modifier and vertex group as shown in the screenshot. I also reassigned the pivot point of the object to be the same as the face anchor, but sill not shown in the desired position

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you figured it out, but for me I had the same issue, what I did was adjust my object relative to people's face instead of google's presets, which may be out of place inside blender.

Now that may not be the best approach because it means you are constantly testing and moving the object in blender to then import to the app, but it works for me.
To circunvent this, I made my own guidelines inside blender, for my specific use case, and place new objects relative to this "custom guide".

Comment: Hello Luis, thanks for your response. so yeah after a lot of trial and error, it did work on some objects but not all of them not sure why. I am doing the exact same process for all of them but still, some show in the desired location, and others do not. The solution you implemented is interesting, I am wondering how did you use people's faces. Did you create a 3D object from 2D images for faces or you did do it another way? and you place the object relative to what exactly?

Comment: Yeah, it's a bummer really, this should be better worked on. Anyway, what I meant was I started experimenting, putting the object I wanted on a given blender coordinate and check if it was anchored where I needed. If not I went back to blender and adjusted slightly. When I was satisfied, I used this position as a "preset" for all other objects that would use that position. (I'm probably not expressing myself clear, but it's simpler than it sounds).

Comment: No, actually it's pretty clear, I understand what you are doing. it's a nice workaround but I assume it will take a lot of time to get the preset coordinates for each set of objects that share the same position. Hopefully, google will solve that in the near future.

Comment: Yeah, I assume so, it's not pratical. In my use case, my objects have the same size, differing only in texture which makes it easier once I set one in place. I'm also hoping they update a lot of things in the future, one of the most wanted in my case is the object oclusion for the front facing cameras. The FF cameras are terribly "outdated" if compared to the possibilities of the back ones.